# How to pass dynamic token in nuxt/apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, nuxt.js, vue-apollo

I want to pass to the headers of my HTTP requests a token that is dynamic, using @nuxt/apollo

I already tried this:

//./nuxt.config.js
apollo: {

```
includeNodeModules: true,
clientConfigs: {
     default: {
     httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/graph/',
    },
    interno: {
      httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/graphiql/',
      httpLinkOptions: {
        headers:{
            Authorization: 'JWT token_static',
        }
      }
    },
  }
},
```

It works, but I need my token to be dynamic.